# Regular Expression Validation in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to allow double data type as

Enter valid price , Maximum upto 6 digits or 4 digits real and 2 fractional

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{4,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Enter valid Price, Maximum upto 6 digits or 4 digits real and 2 fractional.")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
```

I am getting a error on view page as `parsing "^\d+(\.\d{4,2})?$" - Illegal {x,y} with x > y.`

Help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your regular expression syntax, `{4,2}` means at least `4` times and at most `2` times. This is what is causing the error since `4` is greater than `2`. Invert the order and it should work.

That being said, I am not sure if the expression will do what you are after. You can try to use `^(\d{1,6})|(\d{1,4}\.\d{1,2})$` to match either an integer with at most 6 digits or else a fraction with up to 4 digits in the integer part and up to 2 digits in the fraction part.

Comment: Thanks npinti for quick answer